How many $6$ digit numbers are there in which the number '$0$' appeared exactly twice? Other than '$0$' no digit is repeating
The answer is $30240$.
Does we need to divide this by $2!$ As $0$ is there twice?
I don't have answer key for this.
But I attempted it like this.
Places for $0$ can be selected in $_5C_2$ ways. The remaining 4 places can have digits in 9,8,7,6 ways as 0 can be there in first place or else it will be a 5 digit number.
So, $9\times8\times7\times6\times1\times1\times10 = 30240$
My doubt is that, that do we have to divide it by 2!?

I’m voting to close this question because this is a duplicate of your prior question which was closed for lack of context.

No, you don't have to divide by $~2.~$
This is because you computed the number of ways of distributing the $~0$'s as
$~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2},~$ rather than $~(5 \times 4).~$
If you had used the $~(5 \times 4)~$ computation, then you would have been (over) counting each distribution of two $~0$'s twice.
For example, the $~(5 \times 4)~$ computation would have counted $~0~$ in the rightmost two digit places twice: once when the rightmost digit is the first digit counted, and once when the 2nd digit to the right is the first digit counted.
